# How do you use the GPU for 3D rendering in an Adobe Air app

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, air

I'm playing with Air and trying to get the PaperVision3D engine to display some 3D models.

But its really slow since Air seemingly does not support GPU acceleration. Any way to enable GPU rendering in air apps? browser apps can use "wmode=gpu" in the HTML settings...

Comment: I've found PV3d a bit lacking, away3d and alternative look more up to date, plus both are working with adobe+molehill, so once it comes out, they will be able to support the new hardware acceleration.

Comment: also came across this, http://www.bytearray.org/?p=2571  Looks like he is not setting the acceleration, but checking whether it is on `var hardwareCompositing:Boolean = event.hardwareCompositing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to wait for molehill, http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flash/molehill/

the current hardware acceleration is pretty limited.

---

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html

there is some info at the bottom of the page there

> Direct and GPU-compositing window
>   modes
>
> Flash Player 10 introduces two window
>   modes, direct and GPU compositing,
>   which you can enable through the
>   publish settings in the Flash
>   authoring tool. **These modes are not
>   supported in AIR.** To take advantage of
>   these modes, you must enable hardware
>   acceleration for Flash Player.
>
> Direct mode uses the fastest, most
>   direct path to push graphics to the
>   screen, which is advantageous for
>   video playback.
>
> GPU Compositing uses the graphics
>   processing unit on the video card to
>   accelerate compositing. Video
>   compositing is the process of layering
>   multiple images to create a single
>   video image. When compositing is
>   accelerated with the GPU it can
>   improve the performance of YUV
>   conversion, color correction, rotation
>   or scaling, and blending. YUV
>   conversion refers to the color
>   conversion of composite analog
>   signals, which are used for
>   transmission, to the RGB (red, green,
>   blue) color model that video cameras
>   and displays use. Using the GPU to
>   accelerate compositing reduces the
>   memory and computational demands that
>   are otherwise placed on the CPU. It
>   also results in smoother playback for
>   standard-definition video.
>
> Be cautious in implementing these
>   window modes. Using GPU compositing
>   can be expensive for memory and CPU
>   resources. If some operations (such as
>   blend modes, filtering, clipping or
>   masking) cannot be carried out in the
>   GPU, they are done by the software.
>   Adobe recommends limiting yourself to
>   one SWF file per HTML page when using
>   these modes and you should not enable
>   these modes for banners. The Flash
>   Test Movie facility does not use
>   hardware acceleration but you can use
>   it through the Publish Preview option.
>
> Setting a frame rate in your SWF file
>   that is higher than 60, the maximum
>   screen refresh rate, is useless.
>   Setting the frame rate from 50 through
>   55 allows for dropped frames, which
>   can occur for various reasons from
>   time to time.
>
> Using direct mode requires Microsoft
>   DirectX 9 with VRAM 128 MB on Windows
>   and OpenGL for Apple Macintosh, Mac OS
>   X v10.2 or higher. GPU compositing
>   requires Microsoft DirectX 9 and Pixel
>   Shader 2.0 support on Windows with 128
>   MB of VRAM. On Mac OS X and Linux, GPU
>   compositing requires OpenGL 1.5 and
>   several OpenGL extensions (framebuffer
>   object, multitexture, shader objects,
>   shading language, fragment shader).
>
> You can activate direct and gpu
>   acceleration modes on a per-SWF basis
>   through the Flash Publish Settings
>   dialog box, using the Hardware
>   Acceleration menu on the Flash tab. If
>   you choose None, the window mode
>   reverts to default, transparent, or
>   opaque, as specified by the Window
>   Mode setting on the HTML tab.

Also Mike Chambers has some info somewhere about GPU acceleration (look for notes on pewpew), but I think this is all meant for mobile only.

Comment: thanks for the info, but I already knew that, how do I enable HW GPU in AIR?

Comment: if you are using air on a PC, you simply cannot.

Comment: in AIR 2.5 they added some video decoding, I think that is the extent of acceleration. I think it is assigned automatically. This will be of no benefit to 3d though.